# reshaping numpy array / nested arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i have a certain array, say a1 with the below shape

```
a1.shape
(1L, 36L)
```

I want to modify the shape of the this array, such that the desired output should be something like

```
a1.shape
(1L,)
a1[0].shape
(36L,)
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you understand what you are asking for.  But here's the way to do it (for a slightly smaller array):

```
In [48]: a1=np.arange(6).reshape(1,6)
In [49]: a1.shape
Out[49]: (1, 6)
In [50]: a2=np.zeros((1,),dtype=object)
In [51]: a2[0]=a1[0]
In [52]: a2.shape
Out[52]: (1,)
In [53]: a2[0].shape
Out[53]: (6,)
In [54]: a1
Out[54]: array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
In [55]: a2
Out[55]: array([array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])], dtype=object)
```

`numpy` works best when allowed to create and use multidimensional arrays.  Trying to make an array of arrays, or nested arrays is possible, but awkward.

But maybe what you really want is a nested list:

```
In [56]: al = a1.tolist()
In [57]: al
Out[57]: [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
In [58]: len(al)
Out[58]: 1
In [59]: len(al[0])
Out[59]: 6
```

Comment: the reason I need something like this is because i have to concatenate a1 to another array which has shape (2L,) and each row of this array is of shape (36L,). concatenation of two arrays of shape (1L,36L) and (2L,) is my final objective.

Comment: So is that other array a 2 element object array?  How did you construct it?

Comment: Yes, the other array say 'b1' is (2L,) and each row is of shape (36L,). the reason for such as structure is because I am getting the arrays through a list comprehension loop (sequential parsing of webpages). Now, Instead of converting the intermediate outputs to numpy arrays, I am just keeping them as 'list' objects. I would really appreciate if you can direct me to some numpy alternative to running list comprehension